# Springboot Postman "message": "No message available",

Tags: spring-boot, postman

i have a springboot project , when i want to test my method with PathVariable in the Mapping from the **postman** it retruns me that the path is false , but i think there is no mistakes in my controller .

**Controller Class**

```
@Controller
public class AttachmentEmailExampleController {
    @Autowired
    public JavaMailSender emailSender;
    @RequestMapping("/sendAttachmentEmail/{to}")
    @PostMapping()
    public String sendAttachmentEmail(@PathVariable String to) throws MessagingException {
        SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage();
        message.setTo(to);
        message.setSubject("Test Simple Email");
        message.setText("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
        this.emailSender.send(message);
         return "Email Sent!";
    }
}
```

**application.prop**

```
server.port= 8020
```

**PostmanScreenshot**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1W8N.png)

Comment: It may be because of both RequestMapping and PostMapping annotation on the same method. It is not needed. You can simply user @PostMapping("/sendAttachmentEmail/{to}") and remove RequestMapping. OR use RequestMapping with POST method and remove PostMapping.

Comment: @Akash still the same error

Comment: I assume there is no context path set.